# building C library for running in XCode ends up with unsupported architecture

Tags: iphone, c, xcode, build, makefile

i would like to make a sip phone client for iPhones iOS 4.2, therefore i would like to use the pjproject library. I build the library "pjproject 1.8.1.0" like this:
./configure
make dep
make
make install

and the build process ends up without errors. Under /usr/local/lib i see as expected the libraries .a files like "libpjsua-i386-apple-darwin10.5.0.a"
if i start the pj sample test application everything seems to be well.
then i try to link the library to my xcode project but if i try to compile the application i get:

ld: warning: in /usr/local/lib/libpjsua-i386-apple-darwin10.5.0.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

I see that the processor architecture seems to be wrong and i also try to build the library for arm processors since i was not sure if the simulator emulate the processor for iPhone, but this ends up with the error:

ld: warning: in /usr/local/lib/libpjsua-arm-apple-darwin.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Im working on:

Mac OS X 10.6.5
  2 x 2.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon

with the newest iPhone sdk

Has anybody a tip how can i make this library working in my iphone project? I am thankful for any advise.

Comment: You are aware that PJSIP is licensed under GPLv2 which forces you to release your source code as well if you are using it ?

Comment: This is not true see wikipedia

Comment: ok you are right, i figured it is lgpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open ipjsua.xcodeproj using Xcode in pjproject/pjsip-apps/src/ipjsua and build the project.